# Making my own Module vs Using em++ generated module

Tags: javascript, module, emscripten, webassembly

Is making my own `module.js` (fetch parse and create my own Webassembly.Module) a stupid idea? Compared to just using the em++ generated one?

Compiling a program using embind in emscripten yields both my `module.wasm` file and a `module.js`. However the `module.js` file is 1.5MB, and I dont seem to have control over Memory management and such.

I'm currently used a custom compiled c++ program that uses OpenCV, and I keep running out of memeory, I cant allocate the memory properly if I dont create my own Webassembly.Module.

**My Solution:**

I read through `settings.js` (which lies in the same folder as your `em++` executable).

There I learnt that the only flag i needed to set is `-s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1` while compiling.

This allowed me to to decide the TOTAL_MEMORY limit of the module while creating in in javascript.

Comment: I am not a Wasm expert, thats why I haven't voted yet, but I think your question can be improved by further describing your usecase. I think both options have their pros/cons, and as is there aren't enough details for giving an advice.

Comment: Why not using extra em++ option to increate the module memory size?

Comment: @BumsikKim I have the ```-s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1``` option, but it does not seem to help much, because there seems to be a memory max limit that you give to the ```WebAssembly.Memory``` object when you create it. Memory growth cant exceed that.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WebAssembly/Memory#Examples

Comment: @foratseif I just figured out how to increase Memory total size: Found this line in the source code.
```var INITIAL_TOTAL_MEMORY = Module['TOTAL_MEMORY'] || 16777216;``` 
This suggest that you can just set the TOTAL_MEMORY attribute of Module object. when initializing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you want to use emcc/em++ compiler options.

As you mentioned in the comment, you need `-s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1` but it does not do what you may think, and you are not supposed to set `TOTAL_MEMORY` in runtime neither.

You should set `TOTAL_MEMORY` as a compiler flag. For example, `-s TOTAL_MEMORY=100MB`. It is a good idea to keep `-s ALLOW_MEMORY_GROWTH=1` as well.

Documentations doesn't help you at all, I highly recommend reading [`setting.js` from the source code](https://github.com/emscripten-core/emscripten/blob/master/src/settings.js#L87) directly to learn about compiler flags.

Comment: Thank you, I found this out on my own yesterday but this is a perfectly good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested size difference between c++ module that uses opencv and one that does not, difference was `177KB` to `1.5MB`.

This may suggest that yes, it is dumb to attempt to write your own Module object.

But I am not 100% sure.